# Simple solution to get value from dict without knowing its key

Tags: python

Assume there is a `dict` like:

```
{
  "State": "CA",
  "County": "Sonoma",
  "Population": 1200
}
```

And when I want to get the value of `State` if I only know the value of `County`, I write the code below and it works fine.

```py
d = {
  "State": "CA",
  "County": "Sonoma",
  "Population": 900
}

def get_value(value_want, value_know):
    value = [ d[value_want] for k, v in d.items() if v == value_know ]
    # return None if list is empty
    return value[0] if value else None

print(get_value("State", "Sonoma"))
# CA
```

However, is there any simpler way to do this? This code creates a `list` which seems pointless because what I want is just `str` value in the `dict`, not `list`, but I couldn't come up with other ideas...

Comment: You question is ambiguous, do you have only one dictionary of a list of them?

Comment: There is multiple dict stored in the list, and I want to get matching values in a dict.

Comment: you should provide a complete example and the expected output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `d.values()` and `in`:

```
>>> def get_value(d, value_want, value_know):
...     return d[value_want] if value_know in d.values() else None
... 
>>> d = {
  "State": "CA",
  "County": "Sonoma",
  "Population": 900
}
>>> get_value(d, "State", "Sonoma")
'CA'
>>> get_value(d, "State", "Mendocino")
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I fully understood, but assuming you have a list of dictionaries and want to get the first one matching your requirements:

Here is a solution using an iterator. This means you do not have to test all elements for arbitrary long lists:

```
d1 = {"State": "CA",
      "County": "Sonoma",
      "Population": 1200}
d2 = {"State": "XX",
      "County": "Other",
      "Population": 1200}

l = [d2, d1, d2, d2, d2, d2] # this could be infinite, here we want the second item

from itertools import dropwhile, islice
i = iter(l)
list(islice(dropwhile(lambda x: x['County'] != 'Sonoma', i), 1))[0]['State']
```

output: `CA`

Comment: Good example of [abarnert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/908494/abarnert) being right about itertools :-P

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode funny, there's the same saying about regexes, I love both :p

Comment: Not really the same but rather the opposite, as abarnert explains there below it.

Comment: I just see the paragraph below, for some reason if was greyed out

Comment: Alright :-). And when you're done reading that, try `next(generator expression)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to check the value which you provide exists in the values then  you can do it like below. To retrieve the value needed when you have the value_know.

```
d = {
    "State": "CA",
    "County": "Sonoma",
    "Population": 900
}


def get_value(d, value_want, value_know):
    return d[value_want] if value_know in d.values() else None

print(get_value(d, "State", "Sonoma"))
# CA
```